# Laravel - Repetitive query in blade view - Reducing number of queries

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I am in a situation where I have a lot of relationships and it is becoming a problem as it slows down a site when I do a lot of queries.

For instance, I am doing a foreach loop for all blogs and getting the user who made the blog.

```
@foreach ($blogs as $blog)
    <a href="{{ route('blog.view', str_slug($blog->title)) }}">{{ $blog->title }}</a>

    {{ $blog->created_at }}

    <a href="{{ viewProfile($blog->user) }}"><{{ $blog->user->username }}/a>

    Last Commenter:
    <a href="{{ viewProfile($blog->lastCommenter()->user) }}">
        {{ $blog->lastCommenter()->user->username }}
    </a>

@endforeach
```

That alone is more than 50+ queries.. And if there are like 100 blogs, the number of queries is way off.

How can I avoid doing this? I have stored it in a variable in this view but I don't want to really put any PHP code in a blade file. How can I avoid doing this? I have tried using cache in database but that's also doing a few queries to the cache table in database. I am also using eager loading which has helped a lot. But how can I best do this kind of things?

Thank you very much for your response in advance.

Comment: This is why I try to stay away from ORMs. A single sql query would do the same what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @TheDrot, you should just learn how it works. With ORM you'll get much more maintainable and readable code. Tens of JOINS look uglier and much less readable than something like ·App\Book::with('author', 'publisher')->get();·

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I know how they work and yes your points are valid but still your example executes 3 queries and query count goes up with every additional relation which can become a problem with many users using the app. Tens of joins might look uglier but I think every backend web developer today needs to have some knowledge about databases and SQL.

Comment: @TheDrot, my opinion is: OOP over procedural, ORM over raw queries, frameworks over pure PHP. Using all these you're getting an app which is much easier to maiintain (and is cheaper, more robust etc). But that's just my opinion. )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is called N+1 problem. You should learn how to use [Eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) and load relations first. Then iterate over collection to display data to the user.

An example of eager loading of multiple relations from documentation:

```
$books = App\Book::with('author', 'publisher')->get();
```

An example and [tutorial](https://laracasts.com/lessons/eager-loading) suggested by @Achraf Khouadja:

```
$blogs = blog::with('lastCommenter', 'user')->get();
```

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja,  excuse me?

Comment: sorry man the comment is meant for him llol this is awkawrd , wrong place , you did good